# How to parse the array object where each key having multiple values in array?

Tags: javascript, parsing, arraylist

I want to iterate the response and then want to filled this reponse into the data table which i have created.

I have tried using the key values pair reading but couldn't find any relevant method which fits into my type of response.

```
{"1":["Node Down",1,10,19.18,null,null,null,"48.73"],
"2":["Multiple Alerts",2,8,1.37,null,null,null,"35.52"],
"3":["Blank call",3,12,17.81,null,null,null,"24.72"],
"4":["Account Locked or expired or creation",4,13,23.29,null,null,null,"24.46"],
"5":["High Space Used",5,15,32.88,null,null,null,"21.79"],
"6":["Password reset",6,16,30.14,null,null,null,"19.1"]}
```

I want to iterate the result and then filled the result in the dcreated.s which i have created .This response is dynamic and this for one account which i am fetching. In my code i need only the values for `[0],[2],[3],[7]` index only.Any idea how we can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you show an example of the desired result?

Comment: "5":["High Space Used",5,15,32.88,null,null,null,"21.79"],

"6":["Password reset",6,16,30.14,null,null,null,"19.1"]}

Comment: That's the same code you included in your original post. I thought that was the "response" you're getting. If it isn't, what is the response?

Comment: the result is coming like this i want to iterate this over an array and then fill this error into data table which i have created .This result is dynamic

Comment: i am getting the result in this format .

Comment: What do you mean by "fill this error into data table"? What should the table look like? What do you mean by "In my code i need only the values for [0],[2],[3],[7] index only"? There is no "7".

Comment: lets say this is the response "2":["Multiple Alerts",2,8,1.37,null,null,null,"35.52"],

Comment: as you can see the values are coming in  array and there are null values also which is coming in  my response so i want to skip the null values and read the array and then i will store those values in data tables which means HTML table in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Use `.entries` and filter the values which have the keys that you are looking for:

```js
const data = {"1": ["Node Down", 1, 10, 19.18, null, null, null, "48.73"],"2": ["Multiple Alerts", 2, 8, 1.37, null, null, null, "35.52"],"3": ["Blank call", 3, 12, 17.81, null, null, null, "24.72"],"4": ["Account Locked or expired or creation", 4, 13, 23.29, null, null, null, "24.46"],"5": ["High Space Used", 5, 15, 32.88, null, null, null, "21.79"],"6": ["Password reset", 6, 16, 30.14, null, null, null, "19.1"]};

const listOfKeys = ['1', '3', '5', '6'];
console.log(Object.entries(data).filter(([key, val]) => listOfKeys.includes(key)).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val})));
```

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: const listOfKeys = ['1', '3', '5', '6']; this one?  ihis response is coming dynamic and it should iterate all the key and values pair .will this work?

Comment: you can specify in that array the list of the keys that you want to filter. So in the result that will be only the objects with those keys

Comment: i want all the keys dynamically. Can you write this in that way? In the VALUE section you can in my response there are null values i want to skip that values also

Comment: I am sorry, but then I did not understand what do you want to do

Comment: const listOfKeys = ['1', '3', '5', '6']; here i want all the keys which is coming in my response . how can i write this ?

Comment: but if you want all the keys of your response, why you don't simply use the object that you are getting back? what are you filtering then?

Comment: Actually i am new to js .Can you please check my response which i have put in question. The requirement is to read the response.The response format is coming like in my question. I want to use one response and then iterate the other values

Comment: The response i am getting is like one key and multiple values i want to itetate this over an array so that i can display these values in the html table

Comment: i hope i have explained my requirement

Comment: if not please send me email id i will send you the screenshots for better under standing

Comment: Use `Object.values(RESPONSE)` and you will have all the values of your object as array

Comment: this object.values i have used how can iterate this over an  array ? the same format? "1": ["Node Down", 1, 10, 19.18, null, null, null, "48.73"]  like this you can see one key has multiple values ?